# JS Hiding Broken Images Within Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand how to hide images if they're as followed,

```
<img src=""......>
```

However, I'm having problems as I know nothing about JS on how to hide broken images if they're like this,

```
<div class="lx-g3-f" >
  <div class="lx-gallery" data-bg="image_url" alt="alt text" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" title="something title">
  <div class="lx-gallery-title" >
    <h3><a href='something_img_url' referrerpolicy="no-referrer">click here!</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the following work when `img` doesn't exist.

```
$("img").on("error", function() {
    $(this).closest('.lx-g3-f').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not trivial

Try

```
$(function() {
  $("[data-bg]").each(function() {
    const $parent = $(this).closest(".lx-g3-f")
    const img = new Image();
    img.onerror=function() {
      $parent.hide();
    }
    img.src=$(this).data("bg")
  })
})
```

Comment: ```$(function() {
 $("[data-bg]").each(function() {
   const $parent = $(this).closest(".lx-gallery")
   const img = new Image();
   img.onerror=function() {
  $parent.hide();
   }
   img.src=$(this).data("bg")
 })
  })``` worked amazingly well thank you.

Comment: You can just to `const $this = $(this);`  and then `$this.hide()` if you want to hide the div with the background