# Hiding Images With JQuery, but can't seem to find the correct class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to hide broken images with the following code. When I do this, all images `display:none` rather than the affected images. If anyone could help that would be extremely kind. Thanks in advance.

There's a lot of code below, but I wanted to give the full context.

```js
$("img").closest('.mcnImageContent').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300" class="columnWrapper" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="columnContainer" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding: 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" class="mcnImageBlockInner">
                      <table align="left" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                              <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000.png?t=test/gallery_302" title="" class="" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                <img align="center" alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000.png" width="300" style="max-width: 600px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                  class="mcnImage" data-mc-image-bytes="67583" data-mc-width="375" data-mc-height="459" data-mc-natural-width="600" data-mc-natural-height="734">
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                              <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000.png?t=test/gallery_302" title="" class="" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                <img align="center" alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000.png" width="300" style="max-width: 600px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                  class="mcnImage" data-mc-image-bytes="67583" data-mc-width="375" data-mc-height="459" data-mc-natural-width="600" data-mc-natural-height="734">
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                              <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000.png?t=test/gallery_302" title="" class="" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                <img align="center" alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000.png" width="300" style="max-width: 600px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                  class="mcnImage" data-mc-image-bytes="67583" data-mc-width="375" data-mc-height="459" data-mc-natural-width="600" data-mc-natural-height="734">
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                              <a href="https://httpstat.us/404?t=test/gallery_302" title="" class="" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                <img align="center" alt="" src="https://httpstat.us/404" width="300" style="max-width: 600px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                  class="mcnImage" data-mc-image-bytes="67583" data-mc-width="375" data-mc-height="459" data-mc-natural-width="600" data-mc-natural-height="734">
                              </a>
                            </td>
```

Comment: Please remove anything that isn't directly related to the problem (and create a [mcve]) e.g. unnecessary white-space, attributes, ...

Comment: What defines a _"broken"_ image?

Comment: Failing to load, hint the /404 within the image URL.

Comment: the broken image has some kind of class? make normal code

Comment: $ ("img"). closest ('. mcnImageContent'). hide (); - this way you will close all images inside the class `.mcnImageContent`

Comment: Please use CSS instead of inline styling. For one thing it makes the HTML shorter and easier to understand, for another it's faster.

Comment: You'd likely have to attach a handler for `onerror` to each image. Might be easier to leave out the `img` elements' `src` attribute and populate them via JS so you can bind to `onerror` ahead of time.

Comment: it will be useful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815762/detect-when-an-image-fails-to-load-in-javascript

Comment: Didn't you ask something similar in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678812/js-hiding-broken-images-within-class ?

Comment: While you've defined above what you consider a "broken" image - how are you **detecting** them?  You currently have just `$("img")`